# How do I check if a command is "runable" in PHP?

Tags: php

`file_exists()` checks if a file exists.

However, "pg_ctl" is a valid command on my system because `C:\PostgreSQL\bin` is in my `PATH`, so running "pg_ctl" actually runs `C:\PostgreSQL\bin\pg_ctl.exe`.

`file_exists` will report that "pg_ctl" doesn't exist, but it still "kinda" does, since it can run.

How do I check if a given path OR string such as "pg_ctl" translates into a valid command?

I already tried with `realpath`. It returns a boolean false for `realpath('pg_ctl')` , so that doesn't work.

Comment: See [is_executable()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-executable.php).

Comment: @AlexHowansky `var_dump(is_executable('pg_ctl'));` = `bool(false)`

Comment: `is_executable()` requires the full path to the file (or else it looks in the current dir) -- it's not going to traverse your PATH. PHP doesn't care about (or know about) your  PATH -- that's a feature of the shell, not of PHP. If you want to scan through the directories in the PATH, you'll need to do that yourself.

Comment: @AlexHowansky The whole point was for it to check for the command...

Comment: PHP is not the shell, it has no concept of what a "command" is. Shy of a shell exec (which you should not really ever do) you will have to write code to split PATH on colon, iterate over the dirs, and run is_executable() on the command name as if it were a file in that dir.

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I did indeed give up. I wasted countless hours on this and it just wasn't worth it. The Windows command was broken/weird and then I'd have to figure it out for Linux, etc. It's insanity that this is not built into PHP. Nothing useful is built in in anything I use.

Comment: Well `where` in Windows and `which` in Linux probably Mac as well.  One `shell_exec` command.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can use `where.exe` which will return the path to the file if it exists in the path.

```
shell_exec('where pg_ctl');
```

Should return:

> C:\PostgreSQL\bin\pg_ctl.exe

So check for it in the output:

```
$cmd = 'pg_ctl';
var_dump( strpos(shell_exec("where $cmd"), $cmd) !== false );
```

Comment: @AlexHowansky _INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)._ but as with everything don't trust user input, but that doesn't seem the case in this question.

Comment: It still runs the second command after generating that error message. Try `where foo & bar` and you'll get the INFO message and then an error about not being able to run bar.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I know the concept, but my `c:` is still intact ;-)

Comment: If I recall correctly (it's been a while) format prompts for user confirmation by default and there's a switch like `\y` to skip it, but I'm not going to test that. :)